# path errors with snowpack build and cordova build

Tags: cordova, snowpack

Does anyone know of an example snowpack config that works with cordova?
I'm having path errors in my cordova build, which is probably related to relative/absolute path settings.
Couldn't find any examples of snowpack/cordova .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed it.

snowpack.config.js

```
...
buildOptions: {
    baseUrl: "./",
    // default is "/", which I think cordova interprets as absolute path
  },
...
```

Snowpack docs [link](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration#config.buildoptions)